# Creating R repository in Amazon S3

Tags: r, amazon-s3

I created a local R repository using [miniCRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/miniCRAN/index.html) as described in [this Revolution Analytics article](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2014/10/introducing-minicran.html), and it worked so far so good in my machine. All dependencies where tracked, and the installation worked off line without problem.

Then I moved all the donwloaded package structure into Amazon S3 and tried to install it using:

```
install.packages("myPackage"
                 ,repos = "https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/myBucketName/s3CRAN/"
                 ,type = "source"
)
```

I get:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘myPackage’ is not available (for R version 3.2.3)
```

I have made the bucket public, and can download any file if I copy the amazon link and past in my browser.

Any clue?

Comment: Do you have a "PACKAGES.gz" or "PACKAGES" file in your repo? You might try stepping through 'install.packages()' with the debugger if you want to see exactly where it's getting tripped up.

Comment: @MrFlick tks! For http repositories `PACKAGES.gz` is needed, and for local `PACKAGE` is enought, this was the problem. Solved.